# Outlook does not receive messages - PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, outlook, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to make a sending 3 emails with PHPMailer, but I am not having success with receiving these emails in Outlook ....

My code:

```
require_once('mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); 

$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
       'ssl' => array(
           'verify_peer' => false,
           'verify_peer_name' => false,
           'allow_self_signed' => true
       )
    ;

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host = 'mail.myserver.com.br';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Username = 'email@myserver.com'; 
$mail->Password = '******'; //seleciona a porta de envio
$mail->Port = 587; 

$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->From = 'anotherEmail@myserver.com'; 
$mail->FromName = 'My Server'; 

if($reply != NULL){
    $mail->AddReplyTo($reply, $replyNome);  
}

$mail->Subject = "Subject";
$mail->Body = "Test"; //mensagem
$mail->AddAddress('silvio.luis@live.com', 'Silvio'); 

if($mail->Send()){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

I'm getting in Gmail and other email clients, but the outlook does not get the message! ... Below the log:

```
Connection: opening to mail.siteparatatuador.com.br:587, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ),)
Connection: opened
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:29:16 -0300 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:29:16 -0300 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:29:16 -0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 and/or bulk e-mail."
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:29:16 -0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.siteparatatuador.com.br
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 52428800"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 HELP"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 TLS go ahead"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.siteparatatuador.com.br
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 52428800"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 HELP"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
Auth method requested: UNKNOWN
Auth methods available on the server: PLAIN,LOGIN
Auth method selected: LOGIN
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
CLIENT -> SERVER: Zm9ybXVsYXJpb3NAc2l0ZXBhcmF0YXR1YWRvci5jb20uYnI=
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
CLIENT -> SERVER: JmY7N35lazs/RyNs
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "235 Authentication succeeded"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<sitesgerados@siteparatatuador.com.br>
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<silvio.luis@live.com>
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Accepted"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 6 Apr 2016 19:29:16 +0000
CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Silvio <silvio.luis@live.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Stavit <sitesgerados@siteparatatuador.com.br>
CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Assunto
CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <ee92f7c3853944b290aa75c3b441c140@www.siteparatatuador.com.br>
CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.14 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: Teste
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: .
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK id=1ant8e-0001Jc-ER"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1ant8e-0001Jc-ER
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 vps.siteparatatuador.com.br closing connection"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 vps.siteparatatuador.com.br closing connection
Connection: closed
Connection: opening to mail.siteparatatuador.com.br:587, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ),)
Connection: opened
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:29:16 -0300 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:29:16 -0300 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:29:16 -0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 and/or bulk e-mail."
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:29:16 -0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.siteparatatuador.com.br
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 52428800"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 HELP"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 TLS go ahead"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.siteparatatuador.com.br
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 52428800"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 HELP"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
Auth method requested: UNKNOWN
Auth methods available on the server: PLAIN,LOGIN
Auth method selected: LOGIN
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
CLIENT -> SERVER: Zm9ybXVsYXJpb3NAc2l0ZXBhcmF0YXR1YWRvci5jb20uYnI=
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
CLIENT -> SERVER: JmY7N35lazs/RyNs
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "235 Authentication succeeded"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<sitesgerados@siteparatatuador.com.br>
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<silvio.luis@live.com>
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Accepted"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 6 Apr 2016 19:29:16 +0000
CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Silvio <silvio.luis@live.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Stavit <sitesgerados@siteparatatuador.com.br>
CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Assunto
CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <6b10875b6b45c981c884cfd38e2c8701@www.siteparatatuador.com.br>
CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.14 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: Teste
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: .
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK id=1ant8e-0001Jj-Nj"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1ant8e-0001Jj-Nj
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 vps.siteparatatuador.com.br closing connection"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 vps.siteparatatuador.com.br closing connection
Connection: closed
Connection: opening to mail.siteparatatuador.com.br:587, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ),)
Connection: opened
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:29:16 -0300 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:29:16 -0300 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:29:16 -0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 and/or bulk e-mail."
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Wed, 06 Apr 2016 16:29:16 -0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.siteparatatuador.com.br
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 52428800"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 HELP"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 TLS go ahead"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.siteparatatuador.com.br
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 52428800"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 HELP"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-vps.siteparatatuador.com.br Hello vps.siteparatatuador.com.br [192.185.218.52]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
Auth method requested: UNKNOWN
Auth methods available on the server: PLAIN,LOGIN
Auth method selected: LOGIN
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
CLIENT -> SERVER: Zm9ybXVsYXJpb3NAc2l0ZXBhcmF0YXR1YWRvci5jb20uYnI=
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
CLIENT -> SERVER: JmY7N35lazs/RyNs
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "235 Authentication succeeded"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<sitesgerados@siteparatatuador.com.br>
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<silvio.luis@live.com>
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Accepted"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Wed, 6 Apr 2016 19:29:16 +0000
CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Silvio <silvio.luis@live.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Stavit <sitesgerados@siteparatatuador.com.br>
CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Assunto
CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <862ccb186047dc518cfe946419770839@www.siteparatatuador.com.br>
CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.14 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: Teste
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: .
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK id=1ant8f-0001Js-2e"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1ant8f-0001Js-2e
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 vps.siteparatatuador.com.br closing connection"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 vps.siteparatatuador.com.br closing connection
Connection: closed
{"error":false,"message":"Mensagens Enviadas"}
```

Comment: Did you check the "Junk" folder in outlook? A lot of PHPMailer mail end up in the Junk folder, that's why I ask. If you see it their, can you post the headers, outlook will usually tell you the reason why, but not the details as to why.

Comment: Check if your mail server is blacklisted [here](http://www.abuseat.org/). PHPMailer won't tell you if an e-mail was blocked because of an IP blacklist.

Comment: I got yes, but also not. Most strange is that this only happening to Outlook emails. And my ip address 192.185.218.52 is not listed in the CBL.

Comment: Your message *is* being delivered successfully - there are no errors in your SMTP transcript, and `SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1ant8f-0001Js-2e` means the message was received and assigned an ID. If you can't see it, the problem does not lie with how you sent it. Check your junk folder, open a support request with Outlook. For this kind of debugging, `SMTPDebug = 2` is enough - 4 is for debugging connection issues, which you don't have.

Comment: Also you should not disable SSL certificate verification unless you really need to - is outlook really publishing an invalid certificate?

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid, but remove your FROM & FROM NAME part of your mailer and add an unsubscribe option to your body. I just fought with this for a LONG time, Outlook's customer support were terribly useless, and instead I was able to find info online that stated outlook / hotmail has a high spam filter that rejects e-mails that have these tags, ADDReplyTO, etc. It's apparently part of  USA's CAN-SPAM Act of 2003. 
 I hope this helps!